# Maintain column consistency when writing into an existing excel file with pandas to_excel

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, dataframe

this might be a simple and easy problem but I can't find out how to solve it. The problem is more complex but I made a simple version in order to focus in the real issues.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

e = {'col1': [11, 33], 'ab1': [55,44], 'col2': [22, 66]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=e)
with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx',mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, header=True, index=False,engine='xlsxwriter',sheet_name="uno") 
    df2.to_excel(writer, startrow=3, header=False, index=False,engine='xlsxwriter',sheet_name="uno")
```

I have this code where df has:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

df2:

```
   col1  ab1  col2
0    11   55    22
1    33   44    66
```

The current result is

```
   col1  col2  Unnamed: 2
0     1     3         NaN
1     2     4         NaN
2    11    55        22.0
3    33    44        66.0
```

As you can see the column "col2" does not have the values that the df2 has with that key.
so I would like an output like the following:

```
   col1  col2   ab1
0     1     3   NaN
1     2     4   NaN
2    11    22   55
3    33    66   44
```

I cannot change the order in the Dataframes that I am going to insert in the excel since in the real problem they are much larger and they are coming from a mongo db where the inconsistency across different dfs could be greater.

Edit: I forgot to mention a constrain of the system, I cannot have both dataframes in memory at the same time since they have a considerable size. For that reason, one of them is inserted into the excel and deleted and then the other one is created and inserted.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `concat` before write into excel

```
s=pd.concat([df,df2],keys=['df','df2'],sort=True)
s
Out[129]: 
        ab1  col1  col2
df  0   NaN     1     3
    1   NaN     2     4
df2 0  55.0    11    22
    1  44.0    33    66


with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx',mode='a') as writer:
    s.loc['df'].to_excel(writer, header=True, index=False,engine='xlsxwriter',sheet_name="uno") 
    s.loc['df2'].to_excel(writer, startrow=3, header=False, index=False,engine='xlsxwriter',sheet_name="uno")
```

Update

```
col=df.columns
#df.to_excel(writer, header=True, index=False,engine='xlsxwriter',sheet_name="uno")
df2=df2.reindex(columns=col.append(df2.columns.difference(col)))
#df2.to_excel(writer, startrow=3, header=False, index=False,engine='xlsxwriter',sheet_name="uno")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I forgot to mention a big constrain in this problem, I cannot have both df in memory at the same time so once one is inserted, it will be deleted and the next one will be generated